# SQL Server 2012 Join with padded zeros

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two table with a PK ID but one table has a padding 13 digits.

```
Table1
 PK 1234567890000

Table2
PK 123456789
```

What's the best approach when joining?
I have the below join but get an error

```
The conversion of the varchar value '7324004373918' overflowed an int column.

  LEFT JOIN Summary C ON RIGHT('0000000000000',B.Id) = RIGHT('0000000000000',C.id )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RIGHT('0000000000000',Id)
```

Doesn't make any sense. It says you want, say, the right most 7324004373918 characters from the 13 character string `'0000000000000'`.

The best way would be to fix the columns so they both contain the same values and there is no need to do any string manipulation at all.

Failing that you can use either of the following

```
 ON T1.PK = STUFF('0000000000000', 1, LEN(T2.PK), T2.PK)
```

or

```
 ON T2.PK = REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(T1.PK) AS BIGINT))
```

Both make the query unsargable but for different indexes.